# C++ redistributable file was deleted, causes errors when opening Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In a mistake, I removed some file a few months ago. I think it was one of the visual c++ redistributable files. When I open any c++ project, I have about four hundred errors like:

```
cannot open source file "corecrt.h"
cannot open source file "ctype.h"
cannot open source file "errno.h"
cannot open source file "float.h"
cannot open source file "stdio.h"
```

I reinstalled all of the redistributable files and installed all x64 versions but the errors still exist.

What I can do? Can I fix it without reinstalling visual studio?

Comment: _"What I can do?"_ Reinstall Visual Studio. Doesn't have to do anything with the redistributable files. Headers aren't part of these.

Comment: OP may have also removed the Windows SDK. A Visual Studio repair should put that right as well.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you can use the same version installer in order to **repair** the installation rather than getting it brand new.

If you've customized you installation and don't want to lose it try exporting your settings so that you can recover them later. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx)'s more info on this.

Comment: I repaired but I still have one error in targetver.h: cannot open source file: "SDKDDKVer.h" :(

Comment: That looks from the Windows SDK, you need to install that separately